# I want to get its current location first before a nearby places search and optionally after any search or before any search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, w3c-geolocation

I want to get its current location first before a nearby places search and optionally I want to get its current location after any search or before any search. I have a code on how to get its current location, i don't know how to use that as my problem as I just said. The code for how to get the location is from also to google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation, can I fuse it with my code? at https://github.com/patrickesguerra/map

Answer (score 0):

Google's [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) is using [HTML5 Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) to get the user's current location.

To use this in your own code implementation you just need to modify your `initialize` function (where you first load your map) to set both the `center` of the map and the `location` of the nearby search's request to the user's location.

See code below:

```
function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('address')), {
    types: ['(regions)'],
    // componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
  });

  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5666644, 4.7333304);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13
  });

  // HTML5 Geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(pos);

      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch({ location: pos, radius: 10000 }, callback);

    }, function() {
      // Map's center will default to pyrmont
      map.setCenter(pyrmont);
    });
  }
  else {
    // This browser doesn't support Geolocation
    // Map's center will default to pyrmont
    map.setCenter(pyrmont);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can we use it before or after a nearby places search?

Comment: I want is get the current location before or after a nearby places search, I don't know how to use your code to include in mine with the before or after nearby places search.

Comment: Can I use this for getting nearby places search right?

Comment: Oh so what you actually want to do is use the user's current location in the actual nearby search? Yes you can definitely do that.

Comment: See my new edit in the above answer. Copy & paste the exact function. Let me know if this is what you actually meant.

Comment: It displays hotels, can It not display anything first? and then after I check a place to search is says Geocode was not successful for the following reason: INVALID_REQUEST